# Hard to understand the strategy of the following investment.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Upon attempting to solve a problem regarding annuities, I am a little puzzled regarding the following strategy of investment.

> $10,000$ can be invested so that one can purchase an annuity-immediate with **"$24$ level annual payments at an effective annual rate of $10\%$.The payments are deposited into a fund earning an effective annual rate of $5\%$."**

The bolded part is what I am not sure what is going on.

Is $10,000 \over 25$ deposited each year for $25$ years? Under which interest rate, $5$ or $10$?

Or, is it the case that $10,000 \over 24$ is deposited into $24$ intervals during a year which earns $10\%$ effective annual interest, and then that payment is the present value of the annuity that earns $5\%$ annual interest?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're familiar with actuarial notation, so I will be using it. Suppose $X$ is the present value of the payments at $10\%$. Then 
$$Xa_{\overline{24}|10\%}=10,000$$
since in order to receive the annuity-immediate $X$ for 24 years, you have to pay 10,000 (and we assume everything is "actuarially equivalent" in the FM/2 world). **The $5\%$ rate has nothing to do with the pricing of the annuity-immediate**. This distinction is something that people studying for FM/2 consistently struggle with.

For each payment, you throw the payment of $X$ in a new account with interest of $5\%$ (I assume immediately after receiving the payment of $X$). **This new account has nothing to do with the pricing of the annuity-immediate**. Overall, all that is happening in this situation is you get a payment of $X$ and then you throw that payment you receive into a new account with interest so that you can get even more money.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it.  One purchases an annuity whose present value is $10,000$.  The payments are made through out the 24 years spread out evenly, therefore each payment with value $X=\frac{10,000}{a_{\overline{24}\rceil 10\%}}$.  And this is invested immediately to the $5\%$.  Am I on the right ball park?

Comment: @hyg17 - Indeed.